# Передача параметра в awk скрипт

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Надо написать скрипт, который обрабатывает определенный столбец, который предается параметром, но когда я передаю его в виде: `awk -f script.awk text.txt 2` то выдает ошибку `awk: cannot open 2`., где 2 - номер столбца. Как правильно передавать параметры в скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр `-v` для присваивания переменной.
Пример:

```sh
$ more ./tmp.txt
1 a
2 b
3 c
$ awk -v 'x=1' '{ print $x; }' ./tmp.txt 
1
2
3
$ awk -v 'x=2' '{ print $x; }' ./tmp.txt 
a
b
c
$
```